# Print Mapbox XYZ layer using Mapfish/Geoserver

Tags: mapbox, mapfish, mapfish-print

I'm having trouble getting a mapbox XYZ layer to work with the Geoserver Print plugin - I just get the following error:

`spec.layers[0].baseURL has an invalid value`

and a bit further down:

`Illegal character in path at index 79`

My URL is like as so (some parts redacted for privacy):
`https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/*********/*************************/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN`

I assumed that the illegal character might be the curly brace, but of course this is required in the URL.

If I remove this layer, the print works correctly.

The layer is added to the spec using this object:

```
 {
    type: "XYZ",
    baseURL: XYZ, //the url shown above
    extension: "png",
    maxExtent: [0, 0, 700000, 1300000],
    tileSize: 256,
    resolutions: [resolutions], //current map resolution, i.e [40]
    path_format: '${z}/${x}/${y}'
  }
```

I have also added the host to the whitelist in the yaml config:

```
hosts:
- !dnsMatch
  host: api.mapbox.com
```

Geoserver Version: 2.13.0

Has anyone had any success getting this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had constructed my URL incorrectly, the base URL can't contain the z/x/y and the access token needs to be added as a custom param, for example:

```
 {
    type: "XYZ",
    baseURL: 'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/***/***/tiles/256/',
    customParams: {
      access_token: ACCESS_TOKEN
    },
    extension: "",
    maxExtent: map.getExtent(),
    tileSize: [256, 256],
    resolutions: resolutions,
    path_format: '/${z}/${x}/${y}',
  }
```